# .rvmrc file not recognised by Rubymine and Remove Old Rubymine Desktop Launcher

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I upgraded to Rubymine 8 from 6.3. (I am using Ubuntu 12.04)

After upgrading I could not use the icon launcher and was getting the message

"could not execute child process `/home/user...RubyMine-6.3/..`"

So I was simply using `sudo mine` and that was working, but only partially. I could not see the code of the third party gems and I also could not setup my `Settings >> Languages & Frameworks >> Ruby SDK and Gems`. Apparantly Rubymine, on startup, should recognise the .rvmrc file and set this up automatically. But this was not happening for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix: I removed the old desktop launcher:

`locate rubymine`

look for the desktop launcher.. mine was in `/home/username/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-rubymine.desktop`

`rm /home/username/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-rubymine.desktop`

open Rubymine with sudo mine and click `Tools >> Create Desktop Entry` and check the `Create entry for all users` checkbox and click `OK`.

you may need to restart the computer.

Now the RubyMine desktop launcher works as it should, and upon first using it, the Rubymine setup ran and loaded the .rvmrc file as it was supposed to. So I can now see the code of the third party gems among other benefits.

Comment: p.s. working on my project using `sudo mine` was also a very bad idea because all my files had their owner and group changed from `ryan ryan`  to `root root`. had to change them all back via terminal